# How can i convert None field from case class to JSON correctly

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have this case class

```
case class Example(
      exId: String,
      exDes: Option[String] = None)
```

and I try to convert

```
Example(exId = 1)
```

to JSON (example.asJson from io.circe) I actually got

```
{
"exId" : "1"
"exDes": null
}
```

But i expected

```
{
    "exId" : "1"
}
```

is there anyway to convert like i expected with io.circe ?

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `dropNullValues`, as it Scala Docs states:

> Drop the entries with a null value if this is an object.

Your example looks then:

```
Example(exId = "1").asJson.dropNullValues
```

And the result is as you wanted:

```
{
  "exId" : "1"
}
```